# Fast way to convert list of dot-separated strings to YAML?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml

Say I have a list of strings like this:

```
strings = ["foo.bar.1", "foo.bar.2", "foo.bar.A.1", "foo.bar.A.2"]
```

And I want to create a YAML output like this:

```
foo:
  - bar:
     - 1
     - 2
     - A:
         - 1
         - 2
```

Comment: Is that the exact YAML you want, or just something similar? Your function doesn't produce the corresponding data structure, which would be `{'foo': [{'bar': [1, 2, {'A': [1, 2]}]}]}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun I've made the parser.

The idea is to convert the strings

```
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.2
foo.bar.A.1
foo.bar.A.2
too.bar.1
too.bar.2
too.bar.A.1
too.bar.A.2
```

into the table:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | bar | 1 |  |
| foo | bar | 2 |  |
| foo | bar | A | 1 |
| foo | bar | A | 2 |
| too | bar | 1 |  |
| too | bar | 2 |  |
| too | bar | A | 1 |
| too | bar | A | 2 |

Clean columns from duplicated values and add `:` between non empty cells:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo: | bar: | 1 |  |
|  |  | 2 |  |
|  |  | A: | 1 |
|  |  |  | 2 |
| too: | bar: | 1 |  |
|  |  | 2 |  |
|  |  | A: | 1 |
|  |  |  | 2 |

And collapse the table into the yaml-text:

```
foo:
  bar:
    1
    2
    A:
      1
      2
too:
  bar:
    1
    2
    A:
      1
      2
```

Here is the code:

```
import re

strings = [
    "foo.bar.1", "foo.bar.2", "foo.bar.A.1", "foo.bar.A.2",
    "too.bar.1", "too.bar.2", "too.bar.A.1", "too.bar.A.2",
]

# make the table, and reverse it
table = list(reversed(sorted([s.split(".") for s in strings])))

# clean columns of the table
for i,row in enumerate(table[:-1]):
    if table[i+1][0] == row[0]: row[0] = ""
    for c,cell in enumerate(row[:-1]):
        if table[i+1][c] == cell and table[i][c-1] == "": table[i][c] = ""

# add ":" between non-empty cells
for i,row in enumerate(table):
    for c,cell in enumerate(row[:-1]):
        if cell != "": table[i][c] += ":"

# add two spaces into cells
for i,row in enumerate(table):
    for c,cell in enumerate(row):
        table[i][c] = "  " * c + table[i][c]

# reverse table
table = list(reversed(table))

# convert table into yaml
yaml = "\n".join(["\n".join(row) for row in table])
yaml = re.sub(r"\s*\n\s*\n", "\n", yaml, re.MULTILINE) # remove empty lines

print(yaml)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. Well, it's shorter. And it does the job. But I dare not comment it (nobody cares it anyway):

```
strings = [
    "foo.bar.1", "foo.bar.2", "foo.bar.A.1", "foo.bar.A.2",
    "too.bar.1", "too.bar.2", "too.bar.A.1", "too.bar.A.2" ]

strings = list(reversed(sorted(strings)))

for i,s in enumerate(strings[:-1]):
    for c,ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch != strings[i+1][c]: break
    strings[i] = "." * (len(s[:c].split("."))-1) + s[c:]

for i,s in enumerate(strings):
    strings[i] = ":\n".join(["  "*n+c for n,c in enumerate(s.split(".")) if c])

yaml = "\n".join(reversed(strings))

print(yaml)
```

Output:

```
foo:
  bar:
    1
    2
    A:
      1
      2
too:
  bar:
    1
    2
    A:
      1
      2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be looking for 'yaml.dump'.
Ref: http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Here is an example from the referenced doc:

```
import yaml
document = """
  a: 1
  b:
   c: 3
   d: 4
"""
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(document))
give

a: 1
b: {c: 3, d: 4}
```

Full disclosure: I have a lot of YAML experience using Ansible, but I never used this particular feature before. I did a little research and found similar problems being solved with the yaml.dump tool Hopefully it works, it is what I would try.